# Powershell DSC: Run regular code in DSC

Tags: powershell, ssl, server, dsc

I have a DSC I am creating for web server configuration.  My website will be using HTTPS, meaning that I have to have a certificate in a store.  I don't see any modules designed to do this, so I was wondering how I could run regular Powershell functions in a DSC but keep the good parts of the DSC.

My workflow is as follows:

1 . Check if certificate exists

2. If cert doesn't exist in the store, add it.
3. If the cert does exist, grab the the Thumbprint to use in the xWeb xWebsite.BindingInfo.MSFT_xWebBindingInformation.CertificateThumbprint property.

As of now, I've got the code written to do the following actions, but I would still like to make use of the [DependsOn] functionality found in DSCs so I can handle any errors involved with creating/accessing the certificate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

https://serverfault.com/a/638926/236470

Use [Microsoft's xCertificate module](https://github.com/PowerShell/xCertificate) (with the [`xPfxImport` resource](https://www.briantist.com/project/xpfximport-dsc-resource-for-importing-certificates-and-keys/)) for this purpose.

Full disclosure: I wrote the original version of this resource (it's open source in Microsoft's repo now and has since had other contributors).

---

To answer your original question, you would use [the `Script` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/scriptresource) to run arbitrary code without creating your own resource.

Comment: I literally found the xCertificate after I created the question.  Thanks for your help.